# DocuSign API - Email sent to a signer - How do you enable links for HTML content in the email body?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to set the email body for a signer in my DocuSign envelope using the REST API. I am setting it using the emailNotification property for the EnvelopeRecipient (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients).

My concern is that the email body is HTML that has some links, but those links are not clickable in the email. Is there any way to allow for links to be clickable/navigatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a back-end setting for `Allow HTML input in the API`.

You won't be able to configure this setting yourself - you can either reach out to your Account Manager, or have an administrator on the account open a case with [DocuSign Support](https://support.docusign.com) to request that setting be enabled.

If you open a support case, be sure to include your Sandbox account ID if you would like to have it enabled in the Demo environment as well.